# Serial data handling

Tags: python, serial-port, return-value

Can we pass this function value to a variable?

```
import threading
import time

ser = 1#serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
var = 0

def handle_data(data):
    print(data)
    var = data
def read_from_port(ser):
        while True:
           print("reading from serial")
           reading = 1#ser.readline().decode()
           handle_data(reading)
           time.sleep(1)


thread = threading.Thread(target=read_from_port, args=(ser,))
thread.start()
input()
print(var)
```

Not being able to get `var value 1`.

Comment: Try marking `var` as `global` in the `handle_data` function.

Comment: Thank you very much its working :)

Comment: how I can mark it completed?

Comment: I added it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `var` is probably taking a local scope.  Use the python `global` statement, so the interpreter can determine the complete scope of `var`.

e.g.:

```
def handle_data(data):
    global var
    print(data)
    var = data
```

There's a simple tutorial on python globals and variable scope here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/